# Could not load type `A` from assembly `Not.Containing.Type.A`

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

EDIT: I haven't mentioned one **important thing** - application which loads my assemblies are actually not in same directory (as other dlls). After fiddling with Fusion log, I noticed that loading of `dll` are behaving differently than I previously thought. (Yup, I should first RTFM, shame on me)

- `C:\Test\appLoadingStuff.exe`
- `C:\Lib\Acme.Application.dll`
- `C:\Lib\Acme.Data.dll`
- ...

.NET is probing application base (besides GAC and stuff; directory where loading app is - `C:\Test\`), and does not care about location where loaded `dll` are stored (other directory).

---

While using the .NET framework I found myself getting a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` exception:

> System.TypeLoadException
>
> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Could not load type 'Acme.Data.Foo' from assembly 'Acme.Data.Dao, Version=1.1.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"Acme.Data.Foo

I have, for simplicity, 3 assemblies:

- `Acme.Application` my main assembly
- `Acme.Data` my data objects (referenced by 1st one)
- `Acme.Data.Dao` my data access objects (referenced by 1st one)

And there's another application, which actually loads my main assembly. All `.dll` files are in same directory.

As you could expect, type `Acme.Data.Foo` is living in assembly `Acme.Data`. Despite this, .NET is trying to find it in another assembly `Acme.Data.Dao` - which fails, as the type is not there.

I can't figure out what is making .NET looking for that particular type in wrong assembly. Exception is thrown immediately when accessing types on assembly:

```
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:\Lib\Acme.Application.dll")
var types = assembly.GetTypes(); // -> explodes
```

When I tried to check referenced assemblies using:

```
assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

I can clearly see my desired assembly in list.

There's no assembly redirect (and as far I know, this affects only version). Versions of assemblies are correct.

What else should I look for?

Comment: Is there any more detail in the `LoaderExceptions` as suggested by the exception message, or is that what the second message in the post is?

Comment: @MartinCostello yes, that's basically that second message - which makes sense just from half (type is really not there, but assembly where type is is referenced so why it looks for it there)

Comment: Could someone please remove the "Assembly" tag?  I inadvertently wasted my "edit" voting on an edit.

Comment: Can you post the code that's causing the problem, from the code that loads the assemblies?

Comment: @ManoDestra: that's the call `assembly.GetTypes()` indeed there is some LINQ filtering afterwards, but main issue is in getting types.

Comment: No, I mean the code that loads the assemblies, not the types. And, do you have a naming conflict in there e.g. a type called Data, for example?

Comment: @ManoDestra: that's just simple Assembly.LoadFile(path)

Comment: I assume that each of your assemblies builds fine on their own, before you run the code to try to LoadFile on them? May need to see the content of the assemblies, namespaces, etc here. The error suggests that you are trying to load the wrong assembly and hence not getting the required type from it, but I'd need to see what your path is and what it contains inside the assembly referenced at that path.

Comment: @ManoDestra: tried to write simple console app which tries to load assemblies one by one and looks like I have more issues there, need to investigate - but I guess my error occurs because dependent assembly is failing... doh

Comment: Yep, that would definitely do it. Always best to tear everything apart and try to build each component one by one, ensuring all dependencies are in place and they build, etc.

Comment: @ManoDestra: I forgot to mention important thing that app loading my dlls is placed in different directory - and that's why it doesn't work. Now I struggle with writing `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event handler to load properly whole dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated on edited question, I missed to mention very important property of what I was trying to do. My assembly was loaded by another application **which was not in same path** as loaded assemblies.

.NET is probing directory of running application, not directories where loaded dlls are. If one needs to handle such case, it is necessary to implement event handler `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` to take care of dependencies of loaded `dll`.

More reading:

- [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (notice section *Locating the Assembly through Probing*)
- [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Thanks to anyone who participated on this question and sorry I didn't share such crucial detail (tbh, I didn't expect this little detail matters - now i know).